# Fedora SSH client sends RST after 3-way-handshake

Tags: debian, ssh, fedora, openssh, oh-my-zsh

I have a client running Fedora 38 and OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023. The server is an old Buffalo NAS running Debian 11.8 Bulleye, it has OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u3 and OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023.

The ssh connection times out, after hanging at
`debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48`.
In Wireshark I see the client initiating a SYN, the server sends a SYN-ACK, then the server sends ACK and then immediately RST.

```
74446   6348.950713461  192.168.8.198   192.168.8.174   TCP 74  44446 → 22 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=32120 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=3749347152 TSecr=0 WS=128
74447   6348.952546002  192.168.8.174   192.168.8.198   TCP 74  22 → 44446 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65160 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=2278029303 TSecr=3749347152 WS=16
74448   6348.952595078  192.168.8.198   192.168.8.174   TCP 66  44446 → 22 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=32128 Len=0 TSval=3749347154 TSecr=2278029303
74449   6348.952616726  192.168.8.198   192.168.8.174   TCP 66  44446 → 22 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=32128 Len=0 TSval=3749347154 TSecr=2278029303
74453   6353.268747244  192.168.8.198   198.168.8.174   TCP 74  38366 → 22 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=32120 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=4212327032 TSecr=0 WS=128
74459   6354.283146552  192.168.8.198   198.168.8.174   TCP 74  [TCP Retransmission] 38366 → 22 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=32120 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=4212328047 TSecr=0 WS=128
74460   6355.307183990  192.168.8.198   198.168.8.174   TCP 74  [TCP Retransmission] 38366 → 22 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=32120 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=4212329071 TSecr=0 WS=128
```

From another client I can connect, guessing a version incompatibility.

What I have tried without success, is to set
`update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY`
and
`update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:FEDORA32`

However I would expect a clearer error message if it were some crypto incompatibility.
What causes the client to reset the connection instead of sending its protocol version? How can I fix this?

PS Turns out that the connect succeeds when I am root on the Fedora client. Any idea what is missing?

**Update 1:** This is with root... looks as it should.

```
123 49.011405139    192.168.8.198   192.168.8.174   TCP 74  58228 → 22 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=32120 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=3787055761 TSecr=0 WS=128
124 49.014421022    192.168.8.174   192.168.8.198   TCP 74  22 → 58228 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65160 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=2362587143 TSecr=3787055761 WS=16
125 49.014450365    192.168.8.198   192.168.8.174   TCP 66  58228 → 22 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=32128 Len=0 TSval=3787055767 TSecr=2362587143
126 49.014630252    192.168.8.198   192.168.8.174   SSHv2   87  Client: Protocol (SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0)
127 49.016417357    192.168.8.174   192.168.8.198   TCP 66  22 → 58228 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=22 Win=65152 Len=0 TSval=2362587145 TSecr=3787055767
128 49.616114970    192.168.8.174   192.168.8.198   SSHv2   106 Server: Protocol (SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u3)
129 49.616195199    192.168.8.198   192.168.8.174   TCP 66  58228 → 22 [ACK] Seq=22 Ack=41 Win=32128 Len=0 TSval=3787056369 TSecr=2362587700
130 49.617586438    192.168.8.198   192.168.8.174   SSHv2   1426    Client: Key Exchange Init
131 49.618658862    192.168.8.174   192.168.8.198   SSHv2   1146    Server: Key Exchange Init
...
```

**Update 2:** Turned out that it works with every user except the one I am usually using. Also sudo ssh with this one user does not work. I moved the entire .ssh folder of that user to test, no effect. What else can affect the ssh of one specific user?The $HOME variable should have two different values, leading to different dot-file configs being used. Compare those.

**Update 3:** It seems to be related to Oh My Zsh: Found out when I moved the zshrc and opened a new session then it worked. Uninstalled oh my zsh - worked. Reinstalled it and used the default zshrc - didn´t work. Emptied the plugins() - didn´t work. Commented out the source oh-my-zsh.sh - worked.
How the heck can oh my zsh make a difference here?

Update 4: Doing that fixed it. During lots of reboots, updating to Fedora 39, experimenting multiple days - the error persistet. Now after fiddling around with .zshrc the error is gone, don´t know why.

Answer (score 0):

<del>You showed us ephemeral port 44446 making a connection attempt.
When you’re root, it may succeed when the attempt instead comes from a low numbered port.
That is, less than 1024.</del>

---

You have two environments: {broken, working}

Compare the output of `$ which ssh` between the two,
verifying that they are equal.

Compare the output of `$ ssh -v ...` between the two,
to see how far the unprivileged "broken" one gets.

Use `$ type ssh` to convince yourself there isn't
some crazy alias in the middle of this, misleading us.

Compare `env | sort` output between the two environments.
You already examined PATH, so we're looking for things
like LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or the SSH_USE_STRONG_RNG mentioned
on the man page.
Compare `$ ldd /usr/bin/ssh`.
We want to verify the unprivileged user has permission
to read all relevant shared objects.

The $HOME variable should have two different values,
leading to different dot-file configs being used.
Compare *those*.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it... However I added a trace from a connection made with root on client side. It also comes from a high port, but this time the client sends the protocol version - as I would expect from the ssh docs.

Answer (score 0):

Note that after the server sends a SYN-ACK, it is the client's turn to send the ACK... and that's what actually happens, but then **the client** apparently also sends a RST-ACK.

Are you sure you don't have an IP address conflict client-side? That is, your Fedora client 192.168.8.198 initiates the connection, the server responds, but as your client is completing the TCP three-way handshake with an ACK, maybe *some other system or VM* that also has IP 192.168.8.198 configured produces the RST response?

At such an early point, it cannot be a SSH protocol negotiation issue, because *no data has been exchanged yet in either direction*.

You should compare the MAC addresses of the ACK and the RST-ACK packets in the first dump. If they are different, your client system is clearly having an IP address conflict. If they are the same, it might still be some sort of VM/container networking misconfiguration within your client.